# Supporting multiple citation styles

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

I prepared a fairly long document to use with the numbered style of citations (e.g. [1]). Now I am told the paper needs to be submitted to a journal that uses natbib format. This means changing `\cite` to `\citet` or `\citep` or in some places `\citealt`. I'd like to be able to switch back to the original style if needed and essentially support both simultaneously. However, the obvious

```
\newif\ifnatbib
\natbibtrue

\ifnatbib\citet\else\cite\fi{ref1}
```

results in the error

```
! File ended while scanning definition of `\@fortmp`.
```

I am obviously missing something. Hope the fix is simple.

Comment: Can't you use `\renewcommand\cite[1]\citet{#1}`?

Comment: @anderstood Not all the `\cite`s should become `\citet`s. @OP Please provide code for a MWEB (Minimal Working Example with Bibliography) so that people are better able to help you.